# SQL where clause is correct or not in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is the following where clause correct or not in Oracle? because it is not updating the table value:

```
update tableOne set Id_num=1 where name='shweta';
```

Comment: i just added new row to the table and able to update the values . but for the few old records , it is not updating the value

Answer (score 5):

It is correct. Are you getting any errors? Can you do a select for the same where clause?

```
SELECT * FROM tableOne WHERE NAME='shweta';
```

Answer (score 5):

Syntax is correct. But Oracle is case sensitive perhaps you have to use

```
update tableOne set Id_num=1 where upper(name)='SHWETA';
```

And if you are verifing your update by a second application, don't forget to use the

```
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the other rows possibly blank padded? If they are, you wouldn't necessarily notice just by looking at the data.

You could try:

```
update tableOne set Id_num=1 where rtrim(name) ='shweta';
```

OR

```
update tableOne set Id_num=1 where trim(trailing from name) ='shweta';
```

This assumes that is padded by spaces, there may be other whitespace characters that are causing the problem.... or it could be something else entirely.